# Failed to load because no supported source was found. Opera >44

Tags: аудио, браузер, opera

С некоторых пор браузер **Opera** (c версии 44) перестал воспроизводить аудио в формате **aac/m4a**.

Ссылка для примера на основе плеера **jPlayer**:

http://jsfiddle.net/XLNCY/21630/

Пример на основе Soundmanager2 (вкладка MPEG4 / H.264):

http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/page-player/

При попытке воспроизведения в опере выдает ошибку

```
> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found
```

В остальных браузерах всё в порядке.
Проблема не только у меня, начали жаловаться пользователи сайта.

Перелопатил кучу сайтов, ничего не нашел.
Прошу Вашей помощи! Подскажите, как исправить данное недоразумение.